# Python Plotly explress line - how to change the color under the line

Tags: python-3.x, colors, plotly-python

I have the following code

```
daily=pd.read_csv
y_columns= ['1 mo', '2 mo', '3 mo', '6 mo', '1 yr', '2 yr', '3 yr', '5 yr',
   '7 yr', '10 yr', '20 yr', '30 yr']
fig = px.line(daily, x='Date', title='XX')
```

fig.update_layout(title_x=0.5, yaxis=dict(tick0 = 0.2, dtick = 2.5))

with the result
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ceyiz.png)

How to make color under the line, something like that
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0G8Te.png)

Comment: https://plotly.com/python/filled-area-plots/

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for Plotly's [Filled Area Plots](https://plotly.com/python/filled-area-plots/). If you scroll down a little, you'll find the sample code for a Basic Overlaid Area Chart:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[1, 2, 3, 4], y=[0, 2, 3, 5], fill='tozeroy')) # fill down to xaxis

fig.show()
```

I removed the code for the second trace since it looks like you only want to plot a single line.